# gcloud setting env variable for .npmrc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, dockerfile, gcloud

I know there are several posts/questions like this but nothing answered it.
I am using cloudbuild.yaml and reading a secret value from the secret manager and passing it like this.

YAML file

```
entrypoint: /bin/sh 
args: ['-c', 'docker build -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/portal:$SHORT_SHA-${_TARGET} --build-arg token=$$TOKEN . ']
...
```

docker file

```
ARG target=production
ARG token  
 
COPY package*.json ./
COPY .npmrc .npmrc

RUN npm i -g @angular/cli
RUN npm i && mkdir /ng-app && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app
RUN rm -f .npmrc

WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY src ./src
COPY angular.json .
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY tslint.json .
COPY protractor.conf.js .
 
RUN  node --max_old_space_size=8192 $(npm --global bin)/ng build --configuration $target --source-map=true
...
```

.npmrc file

```
@test:registry=https://packages.test.com/npm/js-licensed/
//packages.test.com/npm/js-licensed/:_auth=$token
...
```

My issue is that, it gets the value from google secret manager and populates to the docker file when I echo it out from dockerfile but .npmrc never gets the value so the $token is not valid.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you expect `.npmrc` to be copied to? According to the docker file given, it would be copied to `/.npmrc` because you give a relative path which will be resolved in the `WORKDIR`, and you did not give `WORKDIR` so `/` is used.

Comment: I want it to be the same directory as package.json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copying a file doesn't make replacement of environment variables inside it. If that would happen automatically then you would never get any shell script properly as the environment variables would be evaluated.

The change you will make to your `Dockerfile` will be like below

```
ARG target=production
ARG token  
COPY package*.json ./
ENV token=$token
COPY .npmrc .npmrc.env
RUN envsubst < .npmrc.env > .npmrc && cat .npmrc

RUN npm i -g @angular/cli
RUN npm i && mkdir /ng-app && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app
RUN rm -f .npmrc

WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY src ./src
COPY angular.json .
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY tslint.json .
COPY protractor.conf.js .
 
RUN  node --max_old_space_size=8192 $(npm --global bin)/ng build --configuration $target --source-map=true
```

Comment: @Tarin, thanks.  Can you explain your run command? hard to find a good doc onine.

Comment: `envsubst` command can be given input text with environment variables inside it, it will substitute and output the same on `stdout`. So we redirect it to `.npmrc`

Comment: this didn't work for me, do you mean CMD envsubst?

Comment: Then token needs to be used at build time or at container run-time?

Comment: @Tarin, I get this error  /bin/sh: envsubst: not found

Comment: It's `Tarun` and not `Tarin` :-). Also you will need to install the package `gettext`, depending on which package manager you have, command will be `apk --updated add gettext` or `apt install -y gettext`

Comment: oh my god, so sorry @Tarun.  I see ok.  I will try that. thanks so much

Comment: shouldn't it be this?  RUN rm -f .npmrc.env

Comment: No, once you add a file it will always be there. Even if you remove it in lower layer, it will still be present in previous layers as data. So effectively it doesn't make much of difference if you delete the file or not